# Quartz.NET integration in Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm trying to integrate Quartz in Castle Windsor. I'm using Quartz 2.2.3. and Windsor.QuartzIntegration 0.3.1.
Windsor is version 3.2.1.
But I'm getting the following error.

```
An exception of type 'Quartz.SchedulerException' occurred in Quartz.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: SchedulerPlugin of type '' could not be instantiated.

InnerException:
Cannot instantiate null
Parameter name: type
```

I have already tried for over a day to solve this issue, but I don't have a clue how to fix this anymore. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Quartz config

```
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName">XmlConfiguredInstance</add>
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</add>
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">2</add>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</add>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/quartz_jobs.xml" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.ScanInterval">10</add>
</quartz>
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/castle-project-users

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/castle-project-users/SrnIMl7-3eU/EelKB3HwiokJ

Comment: Yes, I asked the question there as well. Problem is solved. Everything running smoothly now.